# Bell in session 'Default'

Tags: arch-linux

I got a notification on taskbar:

[image]

What it is for? Why did I get that message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use neither Arch nor KDE; but I think the **desktop environment tried to tell you that** [Konsole program](https://konsole.kde.org/), i.e. **terminal just emitted an [XBell signal](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man3/XBell.3.html)**.<sup>1</sup>

When your terminal window did this, **it meant some program *running inside* that terminal just printed ASCII character number 7**, [which means "beep"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character).

Some command line programs do this to signal error or tell user that input sequence he/she entered is invalid. For example: [GNU Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) usually do this when you keep pressing Backspace after you already erased entire command line.

You can test this yourself by dismissing that notification entry, and type in following command in Konsole:

```
echo -e '\a'
```

Once you pressed Enter, you should see that notification popping up again, and you also probably hear system chime sound (or PC speaker beep) too.

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually, I'm not sure if it was just plain XBell, or Konsole also posted KDE notification message for this (i.e. the "*session 'Default'*" part). Nevertheless, the root cause is the same.

Comment: It neither beeps nor gives me any message if I type `echo -e '\a'` and hit enter, I get a blank line on `konsole`.

Comment: @EmonHaque You may have audible bells turned off and the notification would only appear if the terminal isn't on the desktop that is currently active (that's how it usually works anyway).

Comment: @Kusalananda, I went out for a while and logged back in since the screen had been locked, `Konsole` was on the desktop.